# pass environment variable to AzureCli argument in json payload

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

I have a task in my azure pipeline that looks like this

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Request information'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptPath: ${{ parameters.folderName }}/Req-Info.ps1
    arguments: "-urlPath '/api/manageaad/groups/$(groupId)/addowners' -jsonBody '''{ \"owner_object_ids\": \"$($env:servicePrincipalId)\"}''' -urlResource '${{parameters.urlResource}}'"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
```

The problem is that jsonBody always evaluates into line `($env:servicePrincipalId)` rather than the value of `servicePrincipalId`. How to solve that

Comment: That is because you have embedded the jsonbody with single-quotes which makes whatever is in between will be taken literally and does not get expanded to its value

Comment: So how can I fix it? My arguments field also starts with double quotes so I cannot replace it with double quotes either

Comment: You can escape quotes in powershell with backtick `\`"`, combine it with the azure escape `\"` and you should be good to get them through into powershell